# Entity Framework 5 : One to Many with foreignKey Updated/Added/Deleted

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-5

When I update my member, I want to update his BankCheck too.

This is my database:

[image: my database]

- My bankCheck can be added, updated or deleted.
- My member can be updated only (name, surname...)

I choose my member in my datagrid, and select Edit, my wpf app switch to an other page and display my member with Textbox etc.

I click on my button to add/edit/delete his bankCheck and I can edit the first bankCheck.

I delete the last bankCheck and I add an other (for example).

I press OK and I click on "Valid my Edit".

My program re-creates a new Member with his bankCheck and i made this:

```
private void EditMember(Member updatedMember)
{
    try
    {  
        using (var context = new KravMagaEntities())
        {
            context.Member.Attach(updatedMember);
            context.Entry(updatedMember).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        ResetAllControls();
        States.EnumToText(States.StatesEnum.UpdatingSuccess);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _managementService.IsVisibleAddTab(true);
            _managementService.IsVisibleEditTab(false);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        States.EnumToText(States.StatesEnum.Error, exception);
    }
}
```

But I have this error:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

I don't know how I can fix this error.

Thank you.

My code:

```
private void OnEditMemberBtnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var isValidateCertificat = IsValidDate(BirthDateTxt);
        var isValidateBirth = IsValidDate(CertificateDateTxt);
        var isValidateAutorisation = IsValidDate(AutorizationDateTxt);
        var isValidateReglement = IsValidDate(RuleDateTxt);

        if (isValidateBirth && isValidateCertificat && isValidateAutorisation && isValidateReglement)
        {
            States.EnumToText(States.StatesEnum.Updating);

            var typePaiement = BankCheckRadio.IsChecked.Value;
            var typePaiementText = typePaiement ? "Chèque" : "Espèce";

            var doctor = "";
            var dateCertificate = "";

            if (BankCheckRadio.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                doctor = DoctorTxt.Text;
                dateCertificate = CertificateDateTxt.Text;
            }

            var editedMember = new Member
            {
                id_Member = _idForEdit,
                name_Member = UppercaseChar(NameTxt.Text),
                surname_Member = UppercaseChar(SurnameTxt.Text),
                birthDate_Member = BirthDateTxt.Text,
                autorizationDate_Member = AutorizationDateTxt.Text,
                address_Member = UppercaseChar(AddressTxt.Text),
                postalCode_Member = PostalCodeTxt.Text,
                country_Member = UppercaseChar(CountryTxt.Text),
                fixPhone_Member = FixPhoneTxt.Text,
                mobilePhone_Member = MobilePhoneTxt.Text,
                mail_Member = MailTxt.Text,
                beginDate_Member = BeginDateCombo.Text,
                ruleDate_Member = RuleDateTxt.Text,
                subscription_Member = SubscriptionCombo.Text,
                typePaiement_Member = typePaiement,
                typePaiementText_Member = typePaiementText,
                federationNumero_Member = FederationNumeroTxt.Text.ToUpper(),
                level_Member = LevelCombo.Text,
                certificate_Member = CertificateCheckbox.IsChecked.Value,
                doctor_Member = UppercaseChar(doctor),
                certificateDate_Member = dateCertificate,
                problem_Member = UppercaseChar(ProblemTxt.Text, true),
                emergencyName_Member = UppercaseChar(EmergencyNameTxt.Text),
                emergencyPhone_Member = EmergencyPhoneTxt.Text,
                BankCheck = _bankChecks
            };

             if (_bankChecks != null)
                { 
                    using (var context = new KravMagaEntities())
                    {
                        foreach (var bankCheck in _bankChecks)
                        {
                            bankCheck.idMember_BankCheck = editedMember.id_Member;
                            context.Entry(bankCheck).State = EntityState.Added;
                        }
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

            new Task(() => EditMember(editedMember)).Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        States.EnumToText(States.StatesEnum.Error, exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I see, you're updating only `Member`, not all the modified `BankAccounts`. You're updating navigation property of entities from both sides but calling `SaveChanges()` only on entity from one side. So your `Member` starts to refer another `BankAccount` while your `BankAccounts` still refer to the old `Member`. You need to mark all appropriate `BankAccounts` as modified along with your modified `Member` in the same place and then call `SaveChanges()` so everything will be saved *(from comment)*.

To prevent adding a duplicate you can try to set the state of your entities to the `State.Modified` instead of `State.Added`.

The reason of that problem was that you were updating only entity from **one side**. If you have `BankAccounts`-`Members` relationship then in case you update the navtigation property for `Member` you should update a navigation property for `BankAccount` too and vice versa. If you just update some property (`Member.Name` or anything) you just set this `Member`'s `State` to `State.Modified` without affecting any of other `Member`'s, `BankAccount`'s etc.

If the entity tracking is turned on for you then EF will automatically track entities that were modified and set appropriate states for them. But as I've seen from your issue, it's turned off for you so you have to manually set the state for each object you want to add/update/delete.

Comment: Yes I have already found these links... And that's what I did.

Comment: So have you tried everything mentioned there and it didn't help you? From your description, I don't see any critical differences between your problem and the problems mentioned on these links. I don't see the full code so as you have more information you might be able to investigate what are the differences and try to make it working the same as in those examples.

Comment: Also check that you mark entities as modified on BOTH sides (when you update a navigation property for Customer you should update an appropriate BankCheck, too). Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16128818/3731444

Comment: So as I see, you're updating only `Member`, not all the modified `BankAccount`s. You're updating navigation property of entities from both sides but calling `SaveChanges()` only on entity from one side. So your `Member` starts to refer another `BankAccount` while your `BankAccount`s still refer to the old `Member`. You need to mark all appropriate `BankAccount`s as modified along with your modified `Member` in the same place and then call `SaveChanges()` so everything will be saved.

Comment: Ok, i have updated my original code (in my foreach bankCheck). I put Added state to test, it work, but EF create an other Member. I can chat if you want.

Comment: Hey, It work (code updated) ! I have a question, i need to put different state if my bankCheck is updated, or deleted or added ? Or EF can do this ?