# Edit method throws an error : A referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to C# and .NET, I am trying to implement CRUD functionality with a local database. But I get an error when I launch the application. The other method works fine except for the Edit() method.

Here is my Edit method in Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
    {
        Brand brand = _context.Brands
            .Include(e => e.Products)
            .Where(a => a.brand_id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(brand);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Brand brand)
    {
        List<Product> proDetails = _context.Products.Where(d => d.brand_id == brand.brand_id).ToList();
        _context.Products.RemoveRange(proDetails);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _context.Brands.Attach(brand);
        _context.Entry(brand).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.Products.AddRange(brand.Products);

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The entity classes are below
@Brand

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int brand_id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string brandname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string program { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string currency { get; set; } 
    public string note { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime timestart { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime timeend { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

@Product

```
public class Product
{

    [Key]
    public int product_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Brand")]
    public int brand_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; private set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string productname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    public string condition { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nhập thiếu kìa fen.")]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal rebate { get; set; } 
    public string note { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I call them in DbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=ApplicationDbContext")
    {
    }   

    public virtual DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Following error occurs when I launch the Edit

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred
> The property value(s) of 'Brand.brand_id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Product.brand_id' on the other end.

The thing is when I check the database the Brand.brand_id is match with Product.brand_id
[image]
[image]

On the Delete() method now have the same problem.
I am really stuck with this problem and I have no idea what I should change or fix.
I appreciate every help.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128664/a-referential-integrity-constraint-violation-occurred) will probably help you.

Comment: All you need is to return `brand` from the UI with all id values properly set, also in `brand.products`. Stack Overflow has many questions on this topic and it always amounts to adding `HiddenFor` elements to the cshtml.

Comment: Your comment is the answer for my problem 
can you write an answer so that a can accept it

Comment: I think someone should find an appropriate duplicate. My comment is too thin for an answer.